# MongoDB : Search and modify a large number of documents on the basis of an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection in mongoDB containing the information about registered users. Each document has an array containing the info about the friends of the given user.

```
user:{ 
    _id:String,
    phoneNo:String,
    contacts:[{userid:ObjectId}]
    .....
}
```

Now when a user registers from phone I get all the phone numbers from his contacts. I have to
search *each of these phone numbers* in the **users** collection and if they exist I have to push that number to the **user.contacts** array of both the registering user as well as the searched user.

Considering that the user collection to be quite big and I get around 100 phone numbers (*which may or may not exist in the database*) from each of the registering user.

What is the best way to achieve this?